# Pushing a view in Storyboard

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I am trying to use Table Views and navigation controllers. This is the code I would use if I was using NIB files. This piece of code would work fine if I was using NIB files, but I decided to try storyboard -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (_webViewController == nil) {
    self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
}
RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
_webViewController.entry = entry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I have created another scene in storyboard and have everything set up out there. When a user clicks a cell in this Table View they will be taken to that scene. This is what I wrote for the code but it is not right and I'm hopelessly stuck :(  -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"articleView"]){
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    WebViewController *controller = (WebViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.webView = self;
 }
```

**Answer** - Answers 2 and 3 are both right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem 2 days ago, with the user selecting the disclosure accessory on a row and wanting to invoke a segue. What worked for me:

1. In storyboard, create segue "articleView" from the entire tableView controller (not the cell) to the next viewController.
2. Add the following method to your tableViewController:

> ```
> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
>     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"articleView" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
> }
> ```

Just for you I also tested with tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and it works.

Enjoy,

Damien

Answer (score 2):

If your table view is already embedded in a navigation controller (looks that way, from your first code snippet) then the destination view controller of your segue will be a WebViewController, not a navigation controller.

You can therefore have your prepareForSegue method pass the item directly across :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"articleView"])
    {
        WebViewController *controller = (WebViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        controller.entry = entry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find this excellent two-part tutorial helpful

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1